# EntityManager.clear() doesn't stop writing of data to database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation where the user needs to import a file worth of data into a database.  They can select at the start whether to do a standard import and then create a report summary file, or to 'simulate' the import (ie create the same report summary, but not actually import anything).  The basic setup is below:

```
public class Importer {

  @Autowired
  protected IConverter converter;
  @Autowired
  protected ISerializer serializer;
  @Autowired
  protected IReporter reporter;  


  public void import( InputStream stream ) throws Exception {
    CustomerData data = converter.convert( stream ); 
    // ** database at this point has been updated! **
    if( getContext().isSerialize() ) {
       serializer.serialize( data );
    }
    if( getContext().isReport() ) {
       reporter.report( data, "report.xls" );
    }
  }
}

public class Converter implements IConverter throws Exception {
  @Transactional
  public CustomerData convert( InputStream stream ) {
    try {
      CustomerData data = ... // read file and create/match with db entities
      return data;
    } finally {
      if( !getContext().isSerialize() ) {
        // clear any changes made to objects made in the db
        getEntityManager().clear();
        // ** database at this point is unaffected **
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Importer is a bean class configured in Spring 4.1.  Database is JPA 2.1/Hibernate 4.3.11/MySQL 5.5.  Using Java 8.

The CustomerData object is a tree of database entity objects, some of which have been matched with data in the database, (potentially with properties updated with data from the import file) and others which are new entites.

isSerialize() and isReport() allows control over whether the database is updated.  When simulating the import, isSerialize() = false, isReport() = true.

Stepping through the code, when I enter the finally block and clear the entity manager, the data in the database is as it was before the import.  However when I return to the import() method the database has been updated with the changes to the entities!

Clearly the transactional import() method completing commits the data, but why did the clear of the entity manager not stop the changes from happening?  To make sure I set a breakpoint on [Hibernate] AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush() and it's not called at all here.

Could someone please help me understand why clear() doesn't work, and what I should be doing instead.

Comment: maybe rollback the transaction instead?

Comment: Is getEntityManager() getting the entityManager from spring context?

Comment: no reason why clear should not persist; it just removes an object from the L1 cache. Doesn't mean the EntityManager doesn't know about it still

Comment: S.Piller - how do I rollback a transaction when it is being handled by spring @Transactional annotations?

Comment: @Neil Stockton shouldn't clear remove managed entities from the EntityManager, same as detach? My the em shouldn't see changes after that. My guess is clear is called on another EM or the wrapper isn't passing the call through

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, S. Piller for putting me on the right track.  For anyone in a similar position, clearing the entity manager won't stop flushed changes being committed to the database at the end of the transaction - clear() will only clear changed entities since the last flush.

The way around it is to notify the transaction manager that the transaction needs to be rolled back:

```
  @Transactional
  public CustomerData convert( InputStream stream ) {
    try {
      CustomerData data = ... // read file and create/match with db entities
      return data;
    } finally {
      if( !getContext().isSerialize() ) {
        // Ensure the current transaction is rolled back once the topmost @Transactional method completes.
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
      }
    }
  }
```